# jython lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, jython

May I know why the following code does not print out `[1,2,3,1,2,3]`. Instead, it throws an exception. Could you show me how to make it work.

```
x = [1,2,3]
print apply(lambda x: x * 2, (x))
```

if I try the following, it works:

```
test1 = lambda x: x * 2
print test1(x)
```

Comment: Please edit your post, include the full code that does not work, and if possible, the exception you get.

Comment: what does `apply((lambda x: x * 2), (x))` do?

Answer (score 3):

`apply` will take its second argument (which should be a tuple/list) and passes each element of this tuple as positional argument to the object you passed to `apply` as first argument.

That means if `x = [1,2,3]` and you call

```
apply(lambda x: x * 2, (x))
```

`apply` will call the lambda function with the arguments `1`, `2`, and `3`, which will fail, since the lambda function only takes a single argument.

---

To have it work, you should but `x` into a tuple or a list:

```
print apply(lambda x: x * 2, [x])
```

or

```
# note the extra ','. (x,) is a tuple; (x) is not.
# this is probably the source of your confusion.
print apply(lambda x: x * 2, (x,))
```

Answer (score 3):

This works

```
x = [1,2,3]

print apply(lambda x: x * 2, [x])
```

However, it's probably worth noticing that `apply` is deprecated ever since Python 2.3

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply

`Deprecated since version 2.3: Use function(*args, **keywords) instead of apply(function, args, keywords). (see Unpacking Argument Lists)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand your question, but if all you need is to "multiply" list, then simply multiply it:

```
xx = [1,2,3]
print(xx * 2)
```